# How to access a JSON array that is inside a JSON object in Dart?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am a beginner in Flutter and I am trying to build a lyrics app using the API from https://rapidapi.com/brianiswu/api/genius/

The problem is I can't seem to access the array called "hits" that is inside an object called "response"

```
 "response": {
    "hits": [
        {
            "highlights": [],
            "index": "song",
            "type": "song",
            "result": {
                "annotation_count": 5,
                "api_path": "/songs/6419329",
                "artist_names": "ROSÉ",
                "full_title": "Gone by ROSÉ",
                "header_image_thumbnail_url": "https://images.genius.com/04b543b45bb91449afcf59d62ec55be8.300x300x1.jpg",
                "header_image_url": "https://images.genius.com/04b543b45bb91449afcf59d62ec55be8.1000x1000x1.jpg",
                "id": 6419329,
                "lyrics_owner_id": 10919416,
                "lyrics_state": "complete",
                "path": "/Rose-gone-lyrics",
                "pyongs_count": 258,
                "song_art_image_thumbnail_url": "https://images.genius.com/04b543b45bb91449afcf59d62ec55be8.300x300x1.jpg",
                "song_art_image_url": "https://images.genius.com/04b543b45bb91449afcf59d62ec55be8.1000x1000x1.jpg",
                "stats": {
                    "unreviewed_annotations": 0,
                    "concurrents": 6,
                    "hot": false,
                    "pageviews": 1908176
                },
                "title": "Gone",
                "title_with_featured": "Gone",
                "url": "https://genius.com/Rose-gone-lyrics",
                "primary_artist": {
                    "api_path": "/artists/1032508",
                    "header_image_url": "https://images.genius.com/57cb1380a4238e1dcc47fd14c18fc4bc.1000x500x1.jpg",
                    "id": 1032508,
                    "image_url": "https://images.genius.com/a88593efb71bc22510f0d1ec46899da5.1000x1000x1.jpg",
                    "is_meme_verified": false,
                    "is_verified": false,
                    "name": "ROSÉ",
                    "url": "https://genius.com/artists/Rose"
                }
            }
        },
]
}
```

Using the dio and riverpod package, I tried to implement the following code:

```
Future<List<Songs>> getData() async {
Dio dio = Dio();

try{
  final response = await dio.get('https://genius.p.rapidapi.com/search',
      queryParameters: {'q': 'Blackpink'},
      options: Options(headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'genius.p.rapidapi.com',
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'bf5ec94953msh94dc7db178f218cp1f29f2jsn7e7fdfb01965'
      }));
  final data =(response.data['hits'] as List).map((e) =>  Songs.fromJson(e)).toList();
  return data;
} on DioError catch (err) {
  print(err);
  return [];
}


}
```

And this is my factory from Json code:

```
factory Songs.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
return Songs(
    title: json['title'] ,
    url: json['url'] ,
    artist: json['artist_names'] ,
    imageUrl: json['song_art_image_url'],
);


}
```

Comment: You should access it like this `response.data['response']['hits']`

Answer (score 0):

First you have to Decode that Raw data then parse to the map:

```
var rawData=json.decode(response.data);

for(var element in rawData["response"]["hits"]){
   Songs songs=Songs.fromJson(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first decode your response then access to hits in response. Here is an example query

```
var jsonResult = json.decode(response.data);
List<Songs> data =(jsonResult["response"]['hits'] as List<dynamic>).map((e) =>  Songs.fromJson(e)).toList();
```